# CSS Loader after and before trouble

Tags: jquery, html, css, loader

I have this css loader and i need some help on adding few more cercles so i can make it look like this gif right here https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpZfj.gif . I know some css but this is beyond me. I need your support. Thanks

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.33em;
  color: #7E7E7E;
}

h1 {
  color: #EEE;
}

#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 978px;
}

#loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loader {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #3498db;
  z-index: 1001;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
          animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
#loader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #e74c3c;
  -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
          animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}
#loader:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #f9c922;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
          animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 51%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      -ms-transform: translateX(0);
          transform: translateX(0);
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  left: 0;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  right: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
          transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
          transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

.loaded #loader {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
          transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 1s ease-out;
          transition: all 0.3s 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="loader-wrapper">

    <div id="loader"></div>

    <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
    <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>

  </div>


</div>
```